# React-final-form - get state into form values

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-final-form, final-form

I want to 'plug in' a map location picker into some of my forms to add `longitude` and `latitude` into the form values.

I created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-react-leaflet-experiment-g47j8) to demonstrate the difficulties I'm having.

I can get the map `position` into state as the user pans the map, and render the values OK, but I can't get these values into the fields using

```
<Field
 value={position.lat.toFixed(5)}
 ...
/>
```

I need the location picker component `Geo.jsx` to be a separate reusable component to 'plug in' to any react-final-form `Form` if needed. I also need the `latitude` and `longitude` inputs visible and editable for cases when the user wants to manually input these values.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong with this, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by simply changing `value` to `defaultValue`.

On [further reading](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#value) I realised that `value` is only for checkboxes and radio buttons.

Change

```
      <Field
        name="longitude"
        label="Longitude"
        type="number"
        parse={(value) => Number(value)}
        component="input"
     -  value={position.lng.toFixed(5)}
        helper="At map center"
      />
```

to

```
      <Field
        name="longitude"
        label="Longitude"
        type="number"
        parse={(value) => Number(value)}
        component="input"
     +  defaultValue={position.lng.toFixed(5)}
        helper="At map center"
      />
```